# Push notification on windows phone 8.1 from hub

Tags: windows-phone-8

I developed a window mobile phone 8.1 application and register that application to receive push notification under our company account, then i created a hub in windows azure account and copy that package id and secret id in that hub configuration section.

i created a channel using PushNotificationChannelManager then i registered the channel in hub in the application start up OnLaunched event. ( Windows phone 8.1 )

i created a notification hub client and pass the toast template variable in SendWindowsNativeNotificationAsync method.  ( Console application )

Answer (score 1):

You could perform NH registration only for registered users, so only registered users would receive notifications.

It is also possible to perform NH registration via backend (console application). Obviously, to do that your device application should get channel and then pass it to backend somehow (web services or similar). At this point you could enforce any authentication mechanisms, security checks, encryption or whatever you want before register channel in NH. The thing is **only backend** knows NH connection string, it is not exposed with client app and nobody else can create registration even using reverse engineering against device app.

Answer (score 0):

Click configure tab on azure hub, and choose "Enable unauthenticated push notifications" and save, it works!